# No such directory when committing files using CVS from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I am using Eclipse solely as a CVS client. Mostly it works very good, but once in a while, when I am right-clicking a file to commit it (a file that it itself says is changed and ready for commit), it tells me "cvs [server aborted]: no such directory `...'

But the directory DOES exist?! If I navigate to the folder using tortoise CVS and right click for commit, it works fine? (this is the way I finally have to get those files committed)

Has anyone experienced this as well, and more importantly - has anyone solved it? :)
I am running Vista on the client PC and the CVS server is a Windows Server 2003 (please dont tell me to just switch to Linux - that is not much help).

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Eclipse but I faced the same issue with WinCVS client. I could do CVS operations once I copied the `CVS` folder in each directory along the path.

For example: Suppose I am at `C:\source\dir1`. I select the flat-view and find the file with path `C:\source\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.cpp`, I should have the `CVS` folder present in each of following directories: `dir1`, `dir2` and `dir3`. If the one/more folders are not present, we see below error.

```
cvs diff -u -- dir2\dir3\file.cpp (in directory C:\Source\dir1\)
cvs [diff aborted]: no such directory `dir2/dir3'
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution -

1. backup files you have changed in notepad or ...
2. delete folder from eclipse.
3. Synchronise again(eclipse shows files in minus)
4. override and update now.
5. copy contents of changed file
6. commit